# Apple Store - Mavericks/Yosemite Stuck at "Downloading" and actually does NOT continue to download?

Tags: macos, mac-appstore

Good day everyone. I've been at a bit of a bind as of late. I was trying to download Mavericks/Yosemite off of the Apple Store. I open it up, log in, then go to the "Purchased" tab. I scroll down and download `OS X Mavericks`. A confirmation pop up opens:

[image]

I then hit `Continue` to let it download through but I notice that it's just stuck at "Downloading", as seen in the screenshot below:

[image]

It has been sitting like that for roughly 5 minutes. Now, I don't know what to do and how to proceed. I've tried rebooting my laptop but that didn't do anything good, the same issue persisted.

This was the same case for Yosemite.

Any help will be very much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the Launchpad icon in the Dock.
If it's downloading there will be a thermometer [which I've since been informed is actually called a *determinate progress bar*] under it showing progress.

Bear in mind the download might be as much as 6GB, so 5 minutes isn't really much at all unless you have a really fast connection.

[image]

If you rebooted, dropping the connection, then you might have to poke at it a bit to get it going again. It ought to auto-resume, but sometimes gets stuck.
If it did, click Launchpad, find the partial download icon, then hold  <kbd>Opt ⌥</kbd>  & click the X in the top left corner.
Go back to Purchased & start over.

Comment: You said, "_If it's downloading there will be a thermometer under it showing progress._", it is not a thermometer as a thermometer is an instrument for measuring and indicating temperature. It's a determinate progress bar. Have a look at: [Indicator Controls - Progress Indicators](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/OSXHIGuidelines/ControlsIndicators.html)

Comment: Nothing like a good, snappy name for something we see every day, is there? ;)